# Como criar um botão 'próximo registro' de um BD em C#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou tentando fazer um WindowsForm com um botão '**próximo**' para mostrar dados em alguns TextBox vide imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este botão é apenas uma alternativa, ele deve percorrer todos os registros do BD desde o primeiro **SE** o textbox não estiver preenchido, já se estiver preenchido, ele deve percorrer todos registros que contenham o **NOME** parecido com o digitado.

Tentei usar a opção `Reader.NextResult()` mas sem sucesso.

Como devo proceder?

Segue código do botão Pesquisar (lupa):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declara sintrg de conexão com BD
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\xxxxx.accdb");

        //Abrir conexão com BD
        Connection.Open();

        //Declarar Comando SQL
        OleDbCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tb_YYYY WHERE Nome LIKE '%" + txtUserOUNome.Text + "%'";

        //Declarar DataReader
        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            txtPesqNome.Text = Convert.ToString(Reader["Nome"]);
            txtPesqUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(Reader["Usuario"]);
            txtPesqMail.Text = Convert.ToString(Reader["Mail"]);
        }

        //Fechar Reader e Conexão
        Reader.Close();
        Connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: E se armazenar os resultados em uma lista e quando clicar em "next", buscar o próximo ```index```?

Comment: é uma opção, mas não sei como fazer isso, teria um exemplo? :(